# add contextmenu to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, menu, uiimageview, contextmenu

Is it possible to add a contextmenu to a UIImageview?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing app for iPad, then you can use UIPopoverController. On iPhone you have to create your custom view.